# Cannot convert MATLAB y-axis to latex format

Tags: matlab, label, latex, yaxis

I recently started doing some prototyping using MATLAB.  I like to make my axises in latex font because it is consistent with the rest of my writing.  I used the following code:

```
figure()
plot(t, y(:, 1), t, y1, '--r')
legend('Transfer Function', 'State Space', 'Interpreter', 'latex');
xlabel('Time, \textit{t} (s)', 'Interpreter', 'latex');
ylabel('%MeOH in Distillate, \textit{X_D} (%)', 'Interpreter', 'latex');
```

By doing so, I got my x-axis and legend in latex format.  However, my y-axis was not in latex format.. I am wondering why this is.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: It appears that the latex interpreter cannot handle subscripts in italics. The following worked (but terrible font) ylabel('Stuff stuff, X_D','Interpreter','tex') If desired, you could access the handle to the ylabel and set the font and fontangle by hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have messed up some LaTeX syntax. See the highlighted changes:

```
ylabel('\%MeOH in Distillate, \textit{$X_D$} (\%)', 'Interpreter', 'latex');
%       ^                             ^   ^   ^
```

[image: output]

Comment: Ahh ok, I had no idea there would be no errors popping up.  I added the \%, but nothing changed so I thought I was doing something wrong.  But I did not realize I messed up the X_D as well.  Thanks for the answer.